# Cloud Datastore Insert and Upsert Problems

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

I am facing a strange problem while inserting an additional property under an entity key.

[image]

I am trying to add one more property without modifying the existing, however, my below code creates the new property and it deletes the existing Data(Display blank)
As per GCP Doc, I have tried with Insert and upsert not issue not got fixed

```js
server.post('/submit', (req, res,) => {


    const OutTime  = new Date();

 const key = datastore.key([VData, 5717023518621696])
 const entity = {
   key:key,
   method: 'insert',
   data: { content: OutTime },
 }

 datastore.insert(entity).then(() => {
  // Task inserted successfully.
});
// [END datastore_upsert]

});
```

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected, you can't add/modify just a property of an existing entity - the entire entity needs to be re-written. So you need to `get` the entity, add the new property to it then `update`/`upsert` it back to the datastore.

From [Updating an entity](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#updating_an_entity) in the doc you referenced (emphasis mine):

> **The provided data overwrites the existing entity. The entire object must be sent to Cloud Datastore**. If the entity does not exist, the
>   update will fail. If you want to update-or-create an entity, use
>   `upsert` as described previously. Using a [transaction](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#uses_for_transactions) allows you
>   to perform the `get` and `update` operations in a single atomical
>   transaction.

And from [Creating an entity](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#creating_an_entity) (emphasis mine):

> You can save the entity to Cloud Datastore using `upsert` (**which
>   will overwrite an entity if it already exists** in Cloud Datastore)